# Pulling result from XComArgs

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to Airflow and experimenting to understanding the mechanics :)

I see how easy it is to chain python functions with Airflow 2.0 Task Flow API - using @task decorator. What confuses me, is how to pass data from @task decorated functions to custom operators - this is happening automatically when @task decorated functions are chained.

```
def tutorial_taskflow_blob():

   data_path = download_azure_blob_file(blob_file_name, download_dir)
   model_path = xgboost_learner(data_path, model_dir)
   UploadAzureBlobOperator(task_id = "Upload_To_Azure", path_to_file = model_path)
```

lets say that **download_azure_blob_file** and **xgboost_learner** are @task decorated functions and **UploadAzureBlobOperator** is my custom operator. **xgboost_learner** takes **data_path** as argument and works well. but **UploadAzureBlobOperator** doesnt take **model_path**. I'm getting error that instead of string that **xgboost_learner** should be returning, the type of **model_path** is **XComArgs**.

How can I extract data most optimally from **model_path** ? Even if I want to take large dataframe?

Comment: Are you attempting to do any parsing/transformation of the `model_path` value in the constructor of the `UploadAzureBlobOperator`? Is the error occurring during runtime or parse time (i.e. the DAG is not able to be loaded in the Airflow UI)?

Comment: hey @JoshFell! No, I was not parsing in UploadAzureBlobOperator. Although I have found if I define model_path  as template_fields model_path is imported properly. The error was happening during the parse time. Although I'm not sure my approach of template_field is opetimal. :/

Comment: Yes that's the way to go! And the dependency between the "xgboost_learner" and `UploadAzureBlobOperator` tasks should be taken care of automatically too. I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: Thanks @JoshFell for confirming! will this approach work if I want to pass large dataset? or only strings?

Comment: Theoretically "yes" but for "large" datasets it's probably better to use an `XComBackend` or external storage. Just a lot to consider in an Airflow context pulling large datasets into an Airflow environment is all.